# E: Package 'python-wxgtk2.8' has no installation candidate

Tags: pi-4

I'm having trouble installing ''sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk2.8 python-wxtools wx2.8-i18n libwxgtk2.8-dev ''at Pi4.
It failed with:''Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package python-wxgtk2.8 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package libwxgtk2.8-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python-wxgtk2.8' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package wx2.8-i18n
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'wx2.8-i18n'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'wx2.8-i18n'
E: Package 'libwxgtk2.8-dev' has no installation candidate
''

Comment: What do you see with `apt-cache search wxgtk`?

Answer (score 0):

Buster comes with versions 3 and 4.

If you need the older version you may have to build from source and may end up breaking other packages.

```
pi4b:~ $ apt-cache search python-wxgtk
python-wxgtk-media3.0 - Python interface to the wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit (wx.media)
python-wxgtk-media4.0 - Python interface to the wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit (wx.media)
python-wxgtk-webview3.0 - Python interface to the wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit (wx.html2)
python-wxgtk-webview4.0 - Python interface to the wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit (wx.html2)
python-wxgtk3.0 - Python interface to the wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit
python-wxgtk3.0-dev - Development files for wxPython
python-wxgtk4.0 - Python interface to the wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit
pi4b:~ $
```